# Select specific properties for query result

Tags: javascript, dexie

I have the following query:

```
db.asset.where("type").equals(type).each(e => { ... });
```

now `e` holds files (e.binary) as binary strings.
in the each I only want to work on a specific set of properties but on not e.binary, since it slows down the app.
Is there a way to select a set of properties which is returned? 
Or is it only possible to return complete rows?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: yes, by splitting up the data.
One object table holding the binary (or blob in my case) and an uid, which is then crossreferenced at the object, where i stored the binary before.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
db.asset.where("type").equals(type).each(e => {
     return { FirstProperty: e.MyProperty1, SecondProperty: e.MyProperty2 };
}).then(function(myProperties){
   ...
});
```